# Why my bios have no option for usb flashdrive boot

Tags: usb, boot, bios

My main board is Asus P5KPL-AM.I want to install window 7 by my Sandisk flash drive.I setup flash drive with "Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool".i plugged my flash drive and restart and go to bios setting in Boot Device Priority it don't have my flash drive just have only cd,floppy,hdd. what should i do

Comment: try choosing "hdd"

Comment: hdd is my internal hdd it boot window normally not boot from my flash drive

Answer (score 1):

Exit out of boot priority and check to see what the system is set to recognise in the BIOS first, it is possible to turn off things such as USB all together, I don't know the the way around the BIOS for that computer right off hand, I'll google it real quick if you can't find the settings on your own.

Comment: my USB config
USB Functions [Enabled]
USB 2.0 Controller [Enabled]
Legacy USB Support [Auto]
USB 2.0 Controller Mode [Hispeed]

in Boot menu when i go to Hard Disk Drives i can choose my USB:SanDisk but in Boot Device Priority it don't have my SanDisk in Option.

Comment: Let me guess in boot priority it only shows 3 options correct, just highlight one to change it like normal it should show more options to replace it with.

Comment: yes it should show more options(my usb option) but it not show. i don't know why and how i can fix it.